# BroadcastReceiver onReceive is not getting called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have defined a BroadCastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml as below

```
<receiver
   android:name="com.example.hello.ScreenUnlockReceiver" 
   android:enabled="true" 
   android:singleUser="true">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and defined the Receiver as below :

```
public class ScreenUnlockReceiver 
      extends BroadcastReceiver {


   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //start activity
       Intent i = new Intent();
       i.setClassName("com.example.hello", "LoginActivity");
       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

But the broadcastreceiver is not triggered when I unlock the screen and the LoginActivity is not being shown. LoginActivity  is the default loginactivity which comes with android sdk.

Am I missing something in uses-permission or something else, please let me know. 
Thanks

Santhosh

Comment: check rciovati answer its absolutely correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action you have to intercept is:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
</intent-filter>
```

[Developer Android ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did change <action android:name> to android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT as mentioned above and then set the className as mentioned by 3h3 below .... but still the LoginActivity was not started on unlocking the screen by swiping across the screen.

Comment: I'd try to debug and check that the receiver is called properly. Try to check the Logcat to see if there is something that could help you figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

your should fix the problom like this
 `i.setClassName("com.example.hello", "com.example.hello.LoginActivity")`

Comment: I made the change as mentioned by you, but the LoginActivity screen did not show up after unlocking the screen. I am trying to show a default app to the user when the user unlocks the tablet. Let me know if you have any pointers. Thanks

Comment: try this, in the onResume() of your activity, add code like this:<br>`final Window win = activity.getWindow();
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = win.getAttributes();
params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;`<br>I suggest you have a look at the Android source code, the implementation of the AlarmClock,wishes that can help you

Comment: I was actually trying on the emulator and it was not working. Tried the same thing on my phone and it is working.